# How do I use a Rails database record ID as a selector with jQuery-UI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I'm populating a table based on iterations of database records using a ".each do" loop. I want each table cel to have a jQuery-UI dialog box that can fire when the cel is clicked. The problem is, when one cel is clicked, since they all use the same function, it fires hundreds of dialog boxes.

I know this is because I'm using a class selector(class="opener"), but the ID selector isn't working either, I guess because there are hundreds of tables that would share the ID.

```
<table>
  <!-- Loop for each iteration of User -->
  <% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <!-- The email address for current iteration of User -->
    <th style="padding:2.5px;" colspan="5">
      <%= user.email %>
    </th> 
    <!-- Loop for each iteration of a Field for User -->
    <% user.fields.reverse_each do |field| %>
    <td>
      <button class="opener"> Click to open dialog </button>
      <!--  When clicked, it should show a dialog box -->
      <div class="dialog" title="Dialog Title">
        <p>Dialog Content</p>       
      </div>
    </td>
    <!-- End of Field iterations -->
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <!-- End of User iterations -->
  <% end %>
</table>
```

jQuery-UI:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  //= To prevent dialog box from opening automatically
  $( ".dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });

  //= Click HTML element with class ".opener" to open dialog boxes
  $(".opener").click(function () {
    //= Function for dialog box
    $( ".dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
  });
});
```

What I want to do is name the tag class or even the tag ID as "<%= field.id %>" for each iteration in the loop, so that each td tag(class/id) generated is unique to that record iteration. I know that those Rails tags are grabbing the right database values in the HTML because I've checked, I just don't know how to call it in the jQuery-UI functions. Nothing I've tried is working on that front(this.className/this.attr). Do I have to do an AJAX or JSON implementation. If so, how would I go about doing that?

On a side note, does anyone know if Vue.js would be better for what I'm trying to do?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You have several containers (`<td>`s in your case) and inside each container is a button (`.opener`) and a dialog (`.dialog`).

Probably the easiest thing to do is start at the button, go up the DOM to the container using [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), and then come back down to the dialog using [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

```
$(".opener").click(function(ev) {
  let container = $(ev.currentTarget).closest('td'); // Or put a class on the <td> and use closest('.the_class_you_used')
  let dialog    = container.find('.dialog');
  dialog.dialog('open');
});
```

That's all you need if the dialog's content is static. You don't need the `field.id` as long as the button and dialog are in a common container element and no other buttons or dialogs are in that container.

If you did need the `field.id` for something (say an AJAX request to populate the dialog) then you could put a data attribute on the `<td>`:

```
<% user.fields.reverse_each do |field| %>
  <td data-field-id="<%= field.id %>">
```

and then grab it your JavaScript:

```
$(".opener").click(function(ev) {
  let container = $(ev.currentTarget).closest('td');
  let field_id  = container.data('field-id');
```

You could also say `let field_id = container.attr('data-field-id')` if you don't want jQuery to try and interpret the attribute's value.

---

If you're already using jQuery and jQuery-ui then switching to Vue would be a lot of work for just one small feature.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it isn't working. I do need the record for record-specific forms inside the dialog boxes. I'm trying to have a functionality where the dialog box allows editing the record. Even without that functionality, the code you've presented isn't working.

Comment: If you need the `field.id` in JavaScript then use the `data-field-id` attribute, if you need it in the ERB then you already have it.

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that, the button doesn't fire the function at all.

Comment: Do you have a typo somewhere? Anything in the JavaScript console? TurboLinks?